# Get a specific category in multiple categories

Tags: taxonomy

so I have a custom taxonomy called "Service" that can be selected multiple values. Is there a way that I can choose which one will be used to display among of others stay remain for filtering?

Ex:
I select "Car", "Truck", "Bike" but I want to have an option to set "Car" as a main featured of this post and only display "Car" in a place.

My only solution is that create 1 more taxonomy for displaying purpose but it's not practical at all.
Hope you can give me advice

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by making Service taxonomy hierarchical.

- In that case Car would be parent, Bike, Truck children.
- But you can easily display them with non-hierarchical view, same as a simple list what you have got for now.
- In displaying area you can write simple function which would show parent-only choices. (if no any parent cat is chosen, then display children of course)

And that's all i think.